# How to get the route map or multpile points plotted in google map app via Blackberry App

Tags: java, google-maps, blackberry

I am trying to use google maps for my application,I want to know how to get the route map or multiple points plotted in google map app by passing requiring parameters from my app to the Google maps.Insights for it ,will be useful.

I tried using some codes for google map ,and it works good for single location,but for multiple locations,I dont have any info where to search{

```
 URLEncodedPostData uepd = new URLEncodedPostData(null, false);
          uepd.append("action", "LOCN");
          uepd.append("a", "@latlon:" + l.getLatitude() + "," + l.getLongitude());
          uepd.append("title", l.getName());
          uepd.append("zoom", "10");
          uepd.append("description", l.getDescription());



          String[] args = { "http://gmm/x?" + uepd.toString() };

          //String[] args = { "http://maps.google.com/maps?q=12.970214,,77.56029"};
          ApplicationDescriptor ad = CodeModuleManager.getApplicationDescriptors(mh)[0];
          ApplicationDescriptor ad2 = new ApplicationDescriptor(ad, args);
          try {
           ApplicationManager.getApplicationManager().runApplication(ad2, true);`
```

Incase if i want the route info,i dont know what are parameters that needs to be added,AnyInfo on it will be useful

Regards

Rakesh Shankar.P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a developed SDK for RIM in nutiteq.com and you can plot as well as create route map.Best part is ,it works in india too.Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

In the Google maps is not possible to plot multiple points.If you want to use multiple points plotting then its better to you MapQuest API.

You can find it from:

http://developer.mapquest.com/.

Comment: ok ,thank you for info,can i get the route info from between 2 locationss?

Comment: Yes,Doc. is provided on this link:
http://developer.mapquest.com/web/products/dev-services/directions-ws

Comment: Sorry Himanshu,How can i use API for my application,Can you explain it?I got Key,I want to get the image in App,How to use this api?

Comment: How to get the some sort of image in my app.Do i need to use serverside to handle these API's,I am totally blank,Some guidance on this will be helpful.

Comment: Heys Guys,I found  the some sdk developed for RIM  for using various MAps services such as cloudmade.Plz refer nutiteq.com for reference.You can add the JAR file and use the map.